# react-bootstrap doesn't update states inside its Tab.Pane

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

If state is being passed to a component as props, and the component is inside a `Tab.Pane`, when the state changes it won't update its props.

It works only if I programmatically switch tab back and forth with a `setTimeout` of 250 (or manually obviously), which means the tab needs to be switched again to re-render the component (therefore get the updated state)

Strangely enough it's the same thing if instead of a *state* I use a store system as redux to pass the prop to the component.

I also tried to add `mountOnEnter={true} unmountOnExit={true}` to the Pane which btw are already set to the `Tab.Container` wrapping everything inside, but doesn't make any difference.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create a `useState` or a state store of some sort
2. Assign it to a component as prop
3. Place the component inside a **react-bootstrap** `Tab.Pane`
4. Try to change the state
5. The component won't reflect the updated state/store

Version of react-bootstrap used: `"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0"`

example of my Tab.Pane:

```
<Tab.Pane eventKey="items">
   <ItemsList items={data} />
</Tab.Pane>
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Do you find the solution?

Comment: I can anwser the question. can you give me the sandbox?

Comment: I solved doing two identical tabs pane, and via boolean alternate showing results in one or the other. code is too long and nested, if this isn't some weird React rule that I'm missing, then I'm good with the turnaround I found. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try to wrap your tabpane code inside the useMemo hook and add the state which you're passing as a prop in dependency and try. This code will simply re-render your component whenever the state changes.

```
useMemo(() => 
    <Tab.Pane eventKey="items">
       <ItemsList items={data} />
    </Tab.Pane>, 
    [state]
)
```